# Get count of records with field existing in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a MongoDB collection with records in the following format:

```
[
  { "item1": { "a": 1 }, "item2": { "a": 2 } },
  { "item1": { "a": 3 }, "item3": { "a": 4 } },
  { "item1": { "a": 5 }, "item2": { "a": 6 } },
]
```

I want to get a count of records having the fields `item1`, `item2`, and `item3` (They don't need to be dynamic. I have only a finite set of items). What I need is a count of records with field existing in the following fashion:

```
{ "item1": 3, "item2": 2, "item3": 1 }
```

For getting the count for `item1`, I do this:

```
db.collection.find({ "item1": { $exists: true }}).count()
```

Is there an easy way to aggregate the count of all three items in a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to count your keys dynamically:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: { root: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$root"
    },
    {
        $group: { _id: "$root.k", total: { $sum: 1 } }
    },
    {
        $group: { _id: null, obj: { $push: { k: "$_id", v: "$total" } } }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$obj" } }
    },
    {
        $project: { _id: 0 }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Na02AUxzK1G)

Comment: This is great! Is there an easy way to exclude empty keys, say `item5: {}`?

Comment: @YedhuKrishnan sure, you can try this way (additional `$match`): https://mongoplayground.net/p/2Y4RD0mgTZd

Comment: Sorry to bother. I have one last question. Can I get the same count array grouped by a single field? For example, if I have a field called `itemGroup` with values 1, 2, 3 etc. Can I get count per `itemGroup`?

Comment: Not sure if I understand but if you want to follow this approach then just match by `root.k` to filter out all the keys that are different than `itemGroup`